# Programmatically Save Draft in Gmail drafts folder

Tags: java, python, api, gmail

Preferably using Python or Java, I want to compose an email and save it into gmail drafts without user intervention,

Comment: Anyone else looking into this, i have also found: http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/
  
  
But I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: `libgmail` uses mechanize and doesn't work. Last commit was in 2009.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a Python script to access a Gmail account.  First you need to generate an OAuth token.  Download [Google's
xoauth.py module](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough) and run it. It will walk you through the steps. You'll get a url to obtain a verification code -- paste this into the script and it will spit out your token and secret:

```
% python xoauth.py --generate_oauth_token --user=youremail@gmail.com
```

Once you've obtained your token and secret, copy them into the Python script below.  It uses `xoauth.py` to authenticate the IMAP client, connects to IMAP, constructs a message and drops it into the Drafts folder.

```
import email.message
import imaplib
import random
import time
import xoauth

MY_EMAIL = 'youremail@gmail.com'
MY_TOKEN = '<token>'
MY_SECRET = '<secret>'

# construct the oauth access token
nonce = str(random.randrange(2**64 - 1))
timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
consumer = xoauth.OAuthEntity('anonymous', 'anonymous')
access = xoauth.OAuthEntity(MY_TOKEN, MY_SECRET)
token = xoauth.GenerateXOauthString(
    consumer, access, MY_EMAIL, 'imap', MY_EMAIL, nonce, timestamp)

# connect to gmail's imap service.
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.googlemail.com')
imap.debug = 4
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH', lambda x: token)

# create the message
msg = email.message.Message()
msg['Subject'] = 'subject of the message'
msg['From'] = MY_EMAIL
msg['To'] = MY_EMAIL
msg.set_payload('Body of the message')

# append the message to the drafts folder
now = imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time())
imap.append('[Gmail]/Drafts', '', now, str(msg))

imap.logout()
```

Comment: You might also want to check out the [`oauth2` module](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) for authentication with oauth. With that you can just do `imap.authenticate(url, consumer, token)` and don't need to worry about using `xoauth`.

Comment: Thanks for the example code samplebias, that is exactly what I need and I will probably copy it almost exactly if thats ok.

Acorn, thanks for the suggestion of the oauth2 module, I will look into that.

Comment: Yep, I figured best to give you something that works out of the box so you can make progress, then fine tune it later. Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But my problem is one step further.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361257/how-can-i-save-draft-with-details-in-gmail-via-imaplib-in-python). What I want is to set labels to a draft using `imaplib` in python, could you give me an answer? @samplebias

Answer (score 1):

second person to ask something similar today, 
[Using your GMail inbox space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355212/using-your-gmail-inbox-space/5355407#5355407)

you could try doing this using a python imap client: imaplib
quick imaplib+python+gmail returned: http://www.mattwarren.name/2008/08/2/python-imaplib-and-gmail/

a more complicated, but doable way, is using selenium/webdriver. you can automate almost anything.