# Using your GMail inbox space?

Tags: java, gmail, cloud-hosting

Is there any way to store and retrieve data in my Google inbox without having to send emails the whole time and clog up my inbox...? (A simple text file is all I would like to have there)

Or is there some other way of storing files in the google cloud (for free)?

Not that this makes much difference but i'm using Java.

Thanks to whoever has a solution.

Comment: IIRC, this is against their policy...

Comment: does it have to be google mail? couldn't it be google docs?

Comment: Could you use SkyDrive, Amazon S3 or DropBox instead? These offer cloud storage in free, partly free or paid service forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd listen to Mike and check the ToS. However, there's nothing stopping you from keeping a draft email floating around that contains textual data. I use it to pass notes to myself instead of sending emails.

Comment: Yeah I think I will do that... I do that anyway to keep track of songs I like... that kind of stuff. This isn't going to be much data; it's just data that a program of mine will be using. I will try and get that to work like that. Thanks.

Comment: @ExtremeCoder @qor72: They also have several other services ([Google Documents](https://docs.google.com/), [Google Tasks](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/tasks/)) which are actually *meant* for this sort of thing...

Comment: @BlueRaja Agreed. I am not recommending it as a production solution, but it did match what @ExtremeCoder was asking about.

Answer (score 1):

For programing-related stuff, you could try [Google Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/projecthosting/).

Answer (score 1):

Highly likely this is against gmail terms of service. You're likely to get your account deleted if you attempt this.

There were some free/open products years ago that did this ("GDrive" I think was one) and they all were eventually shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, it might be against google's terms of service.
For a good overview of permited interactions with googles services:

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/index.html
http://code.google.com/more/

A quick search didn't show a way to get to mail attachments.

Google mail supports imap, so you might be able to do it
using a java imap client library.

I would use google docs for this though.