# VB.net gmail html draft?

Tags: html, vb.net, email, gmail

Using VB.NET, I would like to create an email and populate subject, to, and body (html), either with window focus or saved in a user's gmail drafts folder if the user is logged into gmail.

I know that I can combine process start and mailto: to set up a short text body in email, but not html body.  Alternate approach?

This question seems similar to [5355067](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355067/programatically-save-draft-in-gmail-drafts-folder) but not using python or java.

ADDED:   The part I find difficult here is to pull the email up in Compose or Draft, instead of using the smtp.send command.  I do know how to send hmtl emails from vb.net, but in this case, I want the user to edit body/text, and add cc:s etc, all in the default gmail client.

Answer (score 0):

I have part of the requirements, check out [the following site](http://www.systemnetmail.com/default.aspx). You will find out how to send messages in html format on [this page](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.2.aspx) of the site. For settings see [the following thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f040bf19-6474-421c-958b-7aa19973b328/vbnet-send-email?forum=vblanguage). All of the above is via the Framework support for SMTP messaging.

To work with a specific folder in gmail you may need to resort to [the api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) for gmail. Most examples are in C# unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for this info.   The part I find difficult here is to pull the email up in Compose or Draft, instead of using the smtp.send command.  I want the user to be able to see the draft in gmail and edit std text there, and to be able to add cc:s etc in the gmail client.   Guess I should edit my question to be clearer.

Comment: You would need to use a richtextbox control, export the richtext to html then set body text taken from the export into the smtp email. Sorry but I don't know of a solid richtext to html converter in vb.net, the one's I have seen are either in C# or are dependent of Microsoft Office being installed and I would guess neither are an option for you.

Comment: I am not in need of a control for the text, "just" a way for vb.net to generate a draft html email inside the gmail web form.  I don't want to send the email, just generate the draft.  Process.start and mailto: can do this crudely, but that only allows for straight ascii I believe.

Comment: I don't have anything for this then, sorry.